# No permission for UID to access URI error on Android Application

Tags: android

I am building a simple app to select an image or take one from camera and crop it. However, it is throwing me this error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10076 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A66
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.grantUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:3948)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.grantUriPermission(ContextImpl.java:1961)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission(ContextWrapper.java:605)
            at err.a(Unknown Source)
            at eru.a(Unknown Source)
            at dwt.b(Unknown Source)
            at dwv.a(Unknown Source)
            at dwv.b(Unknown Source)
            at dwv.a(Unknown Source)
            at dxm.a(Unknown Source)
            at erq.a(Unknown Source)
            at fpb.handleMessage(PG:141)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The code for My Main Activity is

```
package campusconnect.cc.volleyandimage;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String [] items             = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter      = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder       = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
        mImageView            = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE:
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;

        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i            = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res     = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title  = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon         = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions set for the app are

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

I thot that I had given all the permissions necessary to access.. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're missing camera acces

Comment: @SeseSchneider

I put in camera access. I can get the cropper to work when I take the image. But it doesnt work when choosing from gallery

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: @SeseSchneider - It gives me an error saying Google+ cannot be started. But just before that , it gives an error saying that photo editor could not be started and photo could not be loaded

Comment: @SeseSchneider - here is the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/j2Yu9knF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Get image by URI

```
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_IMAGE);
```

This forces the older gallery to open.

Now you can get the result on your `onActivityResult` with:

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
```

Comment: I hope this works for you, I have to leave my computer now, good luck ;)