# No permission grant found for UID and Uri error - Android Xiomi Mi

Tags: android, uri, securityexception

I am trying to allow the user to upload an image from the gallery.

On click of a button `pickFromGallery` -

```
   pickFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 2124);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                }
            });
```

onActivityResult is implemented as so -

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
            Uri originalUri = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                originalUri = data.getData();
            } else {
                originalUri = data.getData();
                final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                try {
                    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
                }
                catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And I get the exception -

```
11-02 19:17:08.848 24468-24468/com.tinystep.app W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10268 and Uri 0 @ file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150612_222143.jpg
```

ONLY on Xiomi Mi (Android Version 5.0.2)

My Manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.wINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

I've looked at [How to persist permission in android API 19 (KitKat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25414352/3765646) and [No permission for UID to access URI error on Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33032902/3765646) but the solutions mentioned there didn't work for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: The `Uri` in question is a `file:///` `Uri`, and I am not aware that there *are* persistable `Uri` permissions for those. Sounds like some `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` implementation is not following the instructions, as the `Uri` you get back should be a `content://` `Uri`, IIRC.

Comment: Exactly you're right, I'm expecting a `content://` `Uri`. But the `Intent` I use opens up the entire folder structure of the phone, not just the gallery and lets me choose any file. Is there another way to just open the gallery?

Comment: "But the Intent I use opens up the entire folder structure of the phone" -- it is supposed to open up the Storage Access Framework UI, which allows the user to pick a provider (for local files or for cloud-based stores like Dropbox or Google Drive). "Is there another way to just open the gallery?" -- no. Even your pre-19 code will not "just open the gallery". That being said, your pre-19 code should still work on Android 4.4+.

Comment: Cool, I'll just use that for all versions then. Thanks! Wonder if I ever find what the problem was here.